# npm install -g creat-react-app NOT WORKING (ERROR 405)

Tags: reactjs, windows, npm, cmd

This happens when i type npm install -g creat-react-app

npm ERR! code E405
npm ERR! 405 Method Not Allowed - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/creat-react-app/creat-react-app

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-03-01T22_47_51_374Z-debug-0.log

Comment: It's spelled `create-react-app` with an "e" at the end of "create".

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

[image: eh]

I also suggest using npx instead of npm as well as removing G

Comment: Hey there. Thank you @Elliot my bad... but still im getting the same errore message                                                                                                           C:\Users\admin>npx install create-react-app
npm ERR! code E405
npm ERR! 405 Method Not Allowed - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/creat-react-app/install

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-02T14_34_38_978Z-debug-0.log